# server code HTTP POST to the remote server - Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

SO I'm trying to call an api from ajax. I've made an ajax call to a local url. Now I want the local url to make the url call and return the returned data. The URL is RESTful.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    accept: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    url: '/postdata/',
    data: {
        "name": "Marcus0.7",
        "start": 500000,
        "end": 1361640526000
        },
    success: function(){alert('DONE!');},
    error:function(error){alert(error)},
    });
```

The api I'm trying to call is (in python):
**This is what I want to implement Server Side** How do I do this?

```
r = requests.post('https//extenal.api' ,headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(data))
```

In Django:

views.py

```
def postdata(request):
    return render(request, 'livestream/postdata.html')
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^postdata$', 'livestream.views.postdata')
```

THanks

Comment: so what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: So you want to do an Ajax post to your view, then do a server-side requests post to an external API?

Comment: Yes, because ajax can not do a cross domain api call.

Comment: ok, so what problems are you having? Your question doesn't give us any information to go on. You *can* do cross-domain requests/posts depending on the server configuration.

Comment: I don't know how to do a request/post from the server? I'm trying to figure out how to receive the ajax call and post the api call.

Comment: You have the `requests.post()` call ready. Just do it and return the response content from the view?

Comment: You will need a view that receives the ajax post, then executes the server-side post using the requests library. Just extend your `postdata` view to execute the call if requuest.method == 'POST'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax CAN do cross-domain calls, but the other domain must allow you to do so by using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

However, if you really just need to reflect an external API from your own domain, you can set your web server to reverse proxy the relevant endpoints of the external API. This will be much more performant than proxying through Django. You can even use your web server to add authentication details into the proxied request.

- [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)
- [Nginx Docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule)